# Resignation After Ultimatum and Pay Reduction - 2 Weeks Notice Required?

Tags: professionalism

Received ultimatum letter identifying previously undocumented performance issues with demotion and pay reduction. This occurred after company acquired and I am last person standing from original senior management team.

Submitted response with cure date prior to pay decrease. Response was to add additional responsibilities and no resolution on response, demotion, pay reduction and hours worked.

Submitted verbal and written resignation. CEO directed me to take a day or two off to think about it and has not accepted resignation. Told him my resignation date is official when I left to think about it.

No change in decision, do I need to provide 2 weeks notice or not?

Comment: Hi Jay. You need to look at the terms of your contract and consult with a lawyer if need be. You shouldn't be asking or taking legal advice from anyone on the internet.

Comment: @Jake : your comment should be a full answer.

Comment: This depends on your contract and/or country. Its possible you can just say "I quit" and walk out if you don't have a contract or an employment law in your country that requires it.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z The correct course of action for any SE site is to comment and vote to close when you know a question is not acceptable, not post an answer saying "this question isn't acceptable for this site."

Comment: @TechnikEmpire - sometimes it's good to inform the OP _why_ the question is being voted closed, so that they may take steps to edit it

Comment: Has it actually been 2 weeks since you gave notice? The fact that the CEO didn't "accept" the resignation at first doesn't seem important, but as others said, you've got to check your contract and/or laywer for a definitive answer.

Comment: Bummer that it's off-topic.  It's still a curious and interesting story, and parts of it may make for a few separate threads on this site.  I'd be interested to hear some suggestions on how to break apart pieces of this question and continue the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

If your resignation is 'not accepted' then you can, if you want, change your mind about resigning. So let's assume you haven't resigned.

In most countries a company cannot arbitrarily make major changes to your salary or job description. If they do, it can be considered tantamount to dismissal (look up 'constructive dismissal'). If the company proceeds with this, **get legal advice before you do anything** - however in many cases the law will treat you as having been disimissed if you resign as a result of such changes, entitling you to severance pay (if applicable), unemployment benefits, and possibly other compensation.

The fact that you were told to 'think it over' seems to me that they want to keep you, and that means **they are open to negotiations**. Go back and negotiate, especially on the salary front. If you negotiate a better package, even if its not what you would want, you can always resign later when you find something better, and you will be paid more while you are looking.

Also make sure you **don't do anything unprofessional** like quitting without notice. Such actions might be used against you if it comes to the law. But your lawyer will tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Nobody can reduce your salary, because that's in your contract. They can *offer* that you accept a reduced salary, and if you don't accept it, they can fire you. With two weeks notice or whatever your notice is, at the full salary.

To be honest, you should have asked here before handing in your resignation. Never jump, wait until you're pushed. (Not literally never, but it's a good rule of thumb). *Maybe* since they didn't accept your resignation, it doesn't count, but if they have it in writing, your chances are slim.

Comment: "Nobody can reduce your salary, because that's in your contract." They can reduce his salary if it's written into his contract.